# What is the equivalent of the oracle query SET UNUSED (Column_name) in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the equivalent of the oracle query SET UNUSED (Column_name) in SQL server?

```
    ALTER TABLE table_name
    SET UNUSED (column_name);
```

Also am looking for SQL equivalent for the dropping Unused column

```
    ALTER TABLE table_name
    DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
```

Could someone please let me know the SQL equivalent of the above oracle statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, apples and oranges.

There is no equivalent statement in SQL Server.

SQL Server doesn't have a mechanism for marking columns as "unused," which is an Oracle extension of SQL.